# Can a user see the In-App Purchase Products anywhere else except in the App?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Does a user see the In-App Purchase Products anywhere else, except in the App? E.g in iTunes or so?

I'm not quite sure this is why i ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the top purchases on the AppStore on the website, iTunes and the AppStore app. However, I don't know what the limit of this list is. On this example application, there are only 6 in app purchases, and all of them are shown. If the app had 100 products, I doubt all would be shown.

These products also probably won't appear until a user has purchased at least one of each product.

[image]

[[Source]](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/angry-gran/id481664999?mt=8)

Comment: That means, as long as no user will buy anything, there won't be displayed any Products? Because this section is named as the "Top In-App Purchases". The thing is, i don't want the user to know, as long as my app doesn't support any in-app purchase products.

Comment: Yes, I think what you said is true.

Comment: If your app doesn't support In-App Purchases, don't put them in yet. Apps have been rejected for not being able to access in app purchases.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint! Do you know, how long it's approximatly going to take Apple to approche an In-App Product?

Comment: Approve? They review them at the same time as the app review.

Comment: Ok?! But as far as i understood, they need to have the App first. And the App needs to be able to handle In-App Purchases. I know, i can create test products but as long as i won't upload any pictures, they won't be reviewed by them. So i will only be able to Upload the Pictures (so Apple knows, some products are reviewable) when the App is already approved, right?

Comment: If you don't upload pictures, but you have enabled In App Purchases, I expect that your app would be rejected.

Comment: So i can create In-App Products that have the pictures uploaded but they won't be reviewed as long as the App won't be uploaded/updated which is able to handle In-App Purchases?

Comment: I'm losing track of what you mean, but I think you have the right idea.

Comment: I think what i mostly fear now are the review guidelines: Are there any guidelines that say: i can't creat a new in-app product (with a picture uploaded) first, before i upload my app, that handles in-app purchases? Or to be more specific: I want to create a product and upload the required image, so Apple can review it. When my app is uploaded and ready, i want these products to appear at the same time, the app is in the appstore.

Comment: `I want to create a product and upload the required image, so Apple can review it. When my app is uploaded and ready, i want these products to appear at the same time, the app is in the appstore.` Good, this is the way it should be done.